# "The format is not supported" when uploading images with %20 / spaces in URL

Tags: bug, images, imgur

I am attempting to upload the following image "from the web" into a post:

URL: http://res2.windows.microsoft.com/resbox/en/windows%207/main/4f6cbd09-148c-4dd8-b1f2-48f232a2fd33_818.jpg

When I do this, the dialog states "Failed to upload image; the format is not supported".

[image]

I have been able to narrow it down, thanks to Mhmd's comment below, to URLs that contain (at least) spaces (I tested on my own server with a file named "astro%20naut.jpg", after URL encoding, although I cannot share the URL).

If I upload direct to imgur from such a URL, there is no problem. It appears to be some issue on the SE side of things.

Comment: You could try upoading it to imgur directly, maybe that gives a more detailed error message

Comment: If I save this on my computer and upload it from there, it works fine, while it doesn't when adding it from the web.

Comment: @MadScientist It uploads just fine direct to imgur.

Comment: It is not about the extension, it is about the url itself since it contains letters that are not supported.

Comment: @Mhmd Good call; I tested and was able to consistently reproduce with URLs with a space in the URL. I've updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: I guess the URL is being decoded somewhere when using the API (probably on SE side) so when it reach imgur, it's not pointing on the correct place anymore.

Comment: I've tried to replace the `%20` by a space, same error. Then I tried to use TinyURL to change the URL, same error again.

Comment: @A.L Replacing with a space is no surprise (I also observed the same thing), but the TinyURL thing *is* a surprise. I wonder why that could be? Must mean the problem is somehow *after* any redirects are handled.

Comment: @Jason C TinyURL is just a redirection to the file, it seems that this doesn't prevent the problem.

Comment: The *format is not supported* can concern the URL or the image itself, for example if the Microsoft website doesn't return the right MIME type.

Comment: @A.L That's a good point. In this case, I did test with my own publicly visible web server, and a few different images, all JPEG, all with correctly reported MIME type of `image/jpeg`, with the same results. The error here in this case is dependent entirely on `%20` or a space in the URL, not on any other factors.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this problem too and made some tests to see what may be causing it. My guess is that it's probably a bug with the function doing the URL validation: If there is even a single character **after** `%20`, the URL would be rejected.

Trying to *mask* the invalid URL using a URL shortener that does [301 redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx) (e.g.  http://goo.gl/Yvkhd5 and http://bit.ly/1pTlrMs) does not work too.

Urls tested to work:

- [`http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?test%20`](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?test%20)
- [`http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20`](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20)
- [`http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%24%3E%22%3C%3D%25%20`](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%24%3E%22%3C%3D%25%20)

Urls tested to **not** work:

- [`http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?test%20test`](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?test%20test)
- [`http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?test%20x`](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?test%20x)
- [`http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?test%200`](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?test%200)
- [`http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20test`](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20test)
- [`http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20%24%20%24`](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20%24%20%24)
- [`http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20;`](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20;)
- [`http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20;x`](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20;x)
- [`http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20;%24`](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20;%24)
- [`http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%24%3E%22%3C%3D%25%20%%24%3E%22%3C%3D%25test`](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%24%3E%22%3C%3D%25%20%25%24%3E%22%3C%3D%25test)
- [`http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20%24%20%24%3E%22%3C%3D%25`](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20%24%20%24%3E%22%3C%3D%25)
- [`http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20%20%20x`](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20%20%20x)
- [`http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20%20x%20`](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20%20x%20)
- [`http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20%20x%20%20`](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20%20x%20%20)
- [`http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20%20x%20%20`](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20%20x%20%20)
- [`http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20x%20x`](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20x%20x)
- [`http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20x%20x`](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20x%20x)
- [`http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20xyz%20xyz%20xyz`](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%20xyz%20xyz%20xyz)