# SE API should handle 302 Found on image upload

Tags: feature-request, api, imgur, uploader

This is the follow-up of [Failed to upload image; the format is not supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279481/191655) which is related to the problem, when certain images can't be uploaded when pasting their URL into the *Image* section (WYSIWYG):

- http://quod.lib.umich.edu/j/jep/images/3336451.0007.104-00000002.gif
- http://quod.lib.umich.edu/j/jep/images/3336451.0007.104-00000006.gif

[@ShadowWizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279522/191655) have investigated the problem and found that it may be a problem with the missing functionality in Stack Exchange API, since it doesn't happen when uploading these kind of images at imgur.com.

So I'm requesting the implementation of that missing functionality which doesn't handle redirect headers while uploading the image (*302 Found*). As for workaround, it's only possible to copy & paste the image into the drop area.

Comment: Actually the workaround is much more simple, just use the "final" url.